# Android CalendarView + Calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar, calendarview

I am currently trying to make it so that when I select a day in a CalendarView, all events for that day are listed. I am having trouble getting it to display all the events in a day (looking like it doesn't work for 12am-11:59am?). Here it what I currently have.

```
calenderView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            getEvents(year, month, dayOfMonth);
        }
    });
```

and

```
public void getEvents(int year, int month, int day){
    log.logInfo("getting events from " + String.valueOf(year) + "/" + String.valueOf(month) + "/" + String.valueOf(day));
    String[] projection = new String[] { CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION };
    // 0 = January, 1 = February, ...
    Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    startTime.set(year,month,day, 00, 00);
    Calendar endTime= Calendar.getInstance();
    endTime.set(year,month,day, 23, 59);
    // the range is all data from 2014
    String selection = "(( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " >= " + startTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ) AND ( " + CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART + " <= " + endTime.getTimeInMillis() + " ))";
    Cursor cursor = this.getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query( CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection, null, null );
    // output the events
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            log.logInfo("Title: " + cursor.getString(1));
            log.logInfo("Start-Time: " + (new Date(cursor.getLong(3))).toString());
            log.logInfo("Location: " + cursor.getString(6));
        } while ( cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    log.logInfo("-----------------------");

}
```

Using this if I have ***event1 from 12am-11:59am*** and ***event2 from 12pm-11:59pm***, only ***event2*** will be listed.

Answer (score 0):

You might try logging the actual times in milliseconds and comparing. `Calendar.getInstance()` will get you a Calendar set to your local time zone, so you're getting all events that start between midnight and 23:59 local time. Are you sure that the database is also all in local time (and not in UTC, or something else)? Just a guess.